# unable to inject $resource, adalAuthenticationService while writing unit-testing for service using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, adal.js

**Data Service**

```js
var dataService = (function() {
      function dataService($q, $resource, adalAuthenticationService) {
        this.$q = $q;
        this.$resource = $resource;
        this.adal = new AuthenticationContext(adalAuthenticationService.config);
      }
});
```

**Test Case**

```js
describe("dataService UT Suite", function() {
  var $q;
  var $resource;
  var adal;
  var dataService;
  beforeEach(module("Utils"));
  beforeEach(inject(function($q, $resource, _adalAuthenticationService_, _dataService_) {
    $q = _$q;
    $resource = $resource;
    adal = adalAuthenticationService;
    dataService = _dataService _;
  }));
});
```

The above service code which is written in typescript file as service named as `dataService`.
I'm unable to inject `$resource`, `adal`, `dataService` in unit tests using jasmine

Can you tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Can you please post your test file? What's the error that your're getting.

Comment: You forgot to close one bracket at the end.

Comment: this is reference file

Comment: Test Case                                                              describe("dataService UT Suite", function () {
    var $q;
    var $resource;
    var adal;
    var dataService ;
    beforeEach(module("Utils"));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_,_$resource_, _adalAuthenticationService_,   _dataService _) {
        $q = _$q_;      
        $resource = _$resource_;
        adal = _adalAuthenticationService_;       
        dataService = _dataService _;          
    })); 
});